# Killing fields and geodesic integral curves

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

My question is if you have a vector field whose integral curves are geodesic, does it imply that vector field is also killing? It seems like it is, just wanted to make sure if it was indeed true.

In particular if I have a smooth function $f$ such that $|\nabla f|=1$, I know that its integral curves are geodesics. I want to verify that $\nabla f$ is also killing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Consider $f(x) = |x|$ in Euclidean $n$-space, $n \ge 2$: its gradient is the radial unit vector field, whose integral curves are the radial rays. As you flow along this field, areas will be stretched in the angular direction, so it certainly does not generate isometries.

Comment: Thanks. I guess if we also had $\text{Hess}f=0$ then we would have a killing field, but I'm curious how weak of a condition do we need so that $\nabla f$ is a killing field.

Comment: @Enigma: A vector field is parallel if and only if it is both Killing and locally a gradient vector field.  In particular, a (global) gradient vector field $\nabla f$ is Killing iff it is parallel -- that is, iff $\nabla \nabla f = 0$ -- i.e., iff $\text{Hess}(f) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks Jesse. This characterization is nice.